# Using JQuery to check for Rel Attribute of Image before Overriding It

Tags: themes, jquery, javascript

My Wordpress theme (when enabled) overrides the rel value of the link of all images with rel="lightbox" using the following code:

http://pastebin.com/Bsh739QY

How can I edit the JQuery to check for the rel value first? If the rel value is already set to "lightbox[xyz123]" or "lightbox[xyz-123|abc]" or "lightbox", then the rel value will not be over-written.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
/*-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
/* Add rel="lightbox" to image links if the lightbox is enabled */
/*-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

if ( jQuery( 'body' ).hasClass( 'has-lightbox' ) && ! jQuery( 'body' ).hasClass( 'portfolio-component' ) ) {
        jQuery( 'a[href$=".jpg"], a[href$=".jpeg"], a[href$=".gif"], a[href$=".png"]' ).each( function () {
                var imageTitle = '';
                if ( jQuery( this ).next().hasClass( 'wp-caption-text' ) ) {
                        imageTitle = jQuery( this ).next().text();
                }
              ;
               if (jQuery(this).attr('rel').indexOf("lightbox") == -1 )
               {
                jQuery( this ).attr( 'rel', 'lightbox' ).attr( 'title', imageTitle );
                }
        });

        jQuery( 'a[rel^="lightbox"]' ).prettyPhoto({social_tools: false});
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. It works. However, I needed to change the operator "!=" to "=" first

Comment: ofcourse...my mistake.. ... -1 means it doesn't have lightbox. Edited my response, and welcome to WPSE